# LINK 1104: Cannot open file '...test.exe' randomly occurred

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, git-bash, googletest

I'm a beginner C++ developer working on a quality assurance project utilizing the GoogleTest framework. While creating unit tests, to verify whether solution outputs were within an acceptable range or not, I received the error message of " LINK1104: cannot open file 'C:Users\kfung\Documents\SAM\sam_dev\ssc\build_vs2017\x64\Release\test.exe' ".

It came out of nowhere. I've been working within the SAM\sam_dev branch for quite sometime now, where I have complete access to this. On top of that, this error message came after trying to build my solution. When this message came, I was only changing integer values, so I do not think it really is linked to that action. It wasn't anything major.

The test.exe program works fine and is able to test all of the files within my test explorer. The program works, yet VS17 is unable to locate/use this file.

I've searched throughout stack overflow and google and nothing like my issue has been discussed. The error has came out of nowhere with nothing really to prompt it.

I've tried "resetting" my development branch on Gitbash using the commands "checkout -- . ", where I should have reverted my project to it's workings state before this occurred. This did not effect my solution where the error keeps occurring.

What should I do?

Comment: Is there an instance of `test.exe` still running?

Comment: Yes, I am able to still launch this program. It still functions as it should.

Comment: That's not what I asked.  Is there an instance _still running_ when you're trying to build?  If there is then VS can't open the file to modify it.

Comment: Oh I understand. After referring to task manager, I did not see it running. That was my way of verifying this, however, not sure if there is a better/different/or correct method in doing so.

Comment: This could also be caused by your antivirus

Comment: I have a very similar error in VS, every second build produces this error. Try simply to build again, for me it works every second build.

Comment: Trying to build again ultimately fails, with the same reoccurring message. However, after consulting with a co-worker internally he took a look at my gitbash history and noticed how my use of the command "git reset" might be the real issue at hand. Does anyone have any experience or troubles when they used the "git reset" command in conjunction with working with other repositories?

Comment: I don't think git has anything to do with the issue. Unless you are resetting to old code that did not compile / thus no executable was produced so you can't run the non-existent executable.

Comment: My coworker/supervisor was convinced about this ... until we tried using the following commands:

git reset --hard upstream/develop,
git status,
git push origin develop --force,

These did not work though. We aren't trying to reset old code that did not compile, but more or less go back into the project where I was troubleshooting a google test that failed under expected values with respect to the outputs.